# LibGDX TextureRegion и TextureAtlas

Tags: android, libgdx

Итак, суть: есть TextureAtlas, где куча картинок. Там же есть картинка, где на одном изображении два корабля. Мне нужно обрезать это изображение по ширине, чтобы на экране отображался только один корабль справа. И зависла я на том, что не могу понять, как именно связать TextureAtlas и TextureRegion. Понятно, что можно просто обрезать саму картинку и собрать их заново, но хочу разобраться в TextureRegion. Я ориентировалась на статью https://habr.com/post/143405/

Сейчас получается так:

```
TextureAtlas mainAtlas;
Hero hero_ship; // корабль
Texture ship;
TextureRegion region;

public void show() {
    mainAtlas = new TextureAtlas("textures/mainAtlas.tpack");
    hero_ship = new Hero(mainAtlas);
    ship = new Texture("textures/mainAtlas.png");
    region = new TextureRegion(ship, 0, 0, hero_ship.getHalfWidth(), hero_ship.getHeight()); // тут ведь явно где-то напутала?
}

public void draw() {
    ...
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(region, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

И можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы hero_ship получил новые размеры и везде вызывать именно его, а не region?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сама сообразила. Всё оказалось просто.

```
 int width =  mainAtlas.findRegion("main_ship").getRegionWidth() / 2;
 region = new TextureRegion(mainAtlas.findRegion("main_ship"), x, y, width, heightShip);
 hero_ship = new Hero(region);
```

И в класс героя передаём регион. Вдруг, кто-то ещё будет также долго думать как и я. :)